# AVPlayer currentTime wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer

Strange issue here.  I'm exporting a video using `AVExportSession`.  It can be composed on of either pre-recorded videos or a video I have captured with an `AVCaptureSession`.  The video rendered from purely a the `AVCaptureSession` video is reporting a correct currentTime in my `AVPlayer` (I'm using a timer to get the current time), however videos created from a video which was capture with the Camera app are reporting incorrect current times.  I get 0.00 for several seconds or even negative values.